# Rewrite rule for relative path?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The error in browser I get is:

```
The requested URL /home/user/public_html/some_folder was not found on this server.
```

And the apache log is:

```
[Sat Aug 17 20:57:57 2013] [error] [client ] File does not exist: /var/www/html/home
```

So naturally I think, I'll try `RewriteBase /../../../home/user/public_html/`, but that gives me:

```
[Sat Aug 17 20:59:22 2013] [error] [client ] Invalid URI in request GET /~user/ HTTP/1.1
```

How do I get around this?

The .htaccess is simple:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /../../../home/user/public_html/

RewriteRule  index.php                 some_folder/index.html  [L]
```

Comment: Sounds like your rewrite rule probably looks similar to this: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /some/value/here` -- if it does, the `/` before the word `some` is telling apache that `/some/value/here` is an absolute url. Instead, try prepending `/home/user/public_html` to the rule so it now looks like this: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /home/user/public_html/some/value/here` and let me (us) know what happens.

Comment: Same error. File does not exist.

Comment: What happens when you just use `RewriteBase /` instead?

Comment: Whoops. I had typed /home/user instead of my actual username... The error I get is `File does not exist: /var/www/html/some_folder`.

Comment: Might take a look at this epic tool as well... [http://static.askapache.com/code/shell/askapache-env.txt](http://static.askapache.com/code/shell/askapache-env.txt)

Comment: You cannot use relative path such as ../ the rewrite rule is tied to the root folder of your httpd.conf virtualhost of the given domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a symlink.

```
cd /var
cp /var/www /var/backup_www
rm -rf /var/www
ln -s /home/user/public_html/ www
```

And enable following symlinks in your httpd.conf.

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/public_html>
    Options -FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

---

Alternatively, just change the DocumentRoot for the server/vhost.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly each step is for? I don't have root access.

Comment: Then this should be configured by your host.  Any decent shared hosting service will provide support.

Comment: Actually I'm not using shared hosting. It's a centos web server set up by my friend, and he doesn't quite understand what the issue is either. I was hoping asking on stackoverflow would clarify for both of us.

Comment: You need root access to properly configure a server.  There's no way around it.  Sometimes someone does it for you... but they do it with root access.

Comment: It's not a vhost AFAIK. It says `<Directory "/home/user/public_html">`. And the symlink wouldn't work because of selinux.